# FullCalendar doesn't return GMT

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to get the start date and the end date from `FullCalendar` I'm using this code:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').start
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').end
```

but the response is like this:

```
Mon Oct 19 2015 00:00:00 GMT +0000
```

How you can see the GMT isn't returned correctly. In the past I'm using the version `1.6.1` and now with the `2.3.1`. With the `1.6.1` the result were this:

```
Mon Oct 19 2015 00:00:00 GMT +0200 (Ora legale Europa Occidentale)
```

This is my FullCalendar initialization:

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        'defaultView': 'multiColAgendaDay',
        'height': BackendCalendar.getCalendarHeight(),
        'editable': true,
        'firstDay': 1,          //Lunedì
        'slotMinutes': 30,
        'snapMinutes': 15,
        'axisFormat': 'H:mm',
        'timeFormat': 'H(:mm)',
        'allDayText': EALang['all_day'], 
        ...
```

There is something that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I couldn't find an answer but since `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').start` and `end` return a momentjs object, this is a momentjs issue.

Comment: uhm so what do you propose for fix this?

Comment: Still looking into it. I can only reproduce this in IE10+11

Comment: I'm also updated moment.js to the last version, nothing is changed..

Comment: It could be related to the deprecated [zz token](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) according to [this discussion](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/162)

Comment: Seems there are no way to fix this actually